# Почему аппетит волчий, а не медвежий?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, идиомы

Нигде так и не нашла информацию об этом, ведь прожорливых хищников очень много, тех, которые могут съесть про запас гораздо больше, чем им нужно сейчас. Вон питон может год не питаться, если антилопу переварит.

Так почему же аппетит именно волчий?

Answer (score 4):

Так повелось - никуда не деться...

Мини-исследование

**[Что такое "волчий аппетит"? Значение и толкование выражения](http://fb.ru/article/268731/chto-takoe-volchiy-appetit-znachenie-i-tolkovanie-vyirajeniya)**

> ...Как-то так повелось, что волк у людей ассоциируется со злым зверем,
>   вечно голодным, беспощадным и коварным. Но на самом деле все хищники
>   живут так, как им предназначено природой. Охотятся они для того, чтобы
>   прокормиться и выходить своё потомство, а не ради удовольствия. И
>   коварства в их поведении нет абсолютно. Поговорка «Волка ноги кормят»
>   как раз указывает на то, что пропитание этим животным достаётся
>   трудом. И покушать им, увы, удаётся не каждый день. Вероятно, поэтому
>   волки едят с большим аппетитом. Им же нужно восстановить затраченную
>   на поиски пропитания энергию.
>
> Почему именно волка выбрали в качестве главного действующего лица в
>   выражении, которое описывает сильный голод, - непонятно. Ведь жадно
>   едят все живые существа, которые долго были лишены питания. Достаточно
>   посмотреть, как давится едой подобранный на улице котёнок или
>   захлёбывается молоком телёнок, отлученный от матери и длительный
>   период не имеющий возможности пить молоко из плошки. Но именно волк
>   стал тем животным, которого взяли в качестве прототипа в данной фразе.
>   Вероятно, тому причиной был тот факт, что волк не всегда имеет
>   возможность насытиться. Ведь в естественной среде обитания ему
>   довольно сложно находить себе пропитание. Крупных травоядных победить
>   в одиночку трудно, а в стае лося либо косулю приходится делить на
>   многих. Мелкими же животными насытиться тяжело.